# What's the best way to approach multiple users inputting, and pulling images consistently in a program?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-applications, automation, storage

I'm creating a web app that would allow users to send up to 12 images from their computer to be stored in this program, and have them pulled consistently while the program is running. For each new user using the app, they would have their own images that would need to be stored and pulled.

I've created the program locally and it works perfectly, but i'm trying to scale it and make it available to other users. Right now, i'm using GCP and am pushing the images to storage, but i'm thinking this could get expensive fast. Any suggestions on the best way to approach this?

Maybe a tempstore? Not sure how easy it is to pull those images though, as I have no experience with it.

Anyway, open to any suggestions.

Comment: what do you mean by "pulling images"? Downloading them back to users?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage is definitely a viable solution. Depending on the frequency of accessing images you might profit from different types of [storage access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko it's to post images on a platform, so pulling the images from gcp and pushing them to platform